# For comprehension with two generators

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I want to display an arbitrary number of strings in a GUI-application in a vertical list.

Consider the following example:

```
val names = Seq[String]("Boris", "Anna", "Markus", "Simone")

for(a <- 1 to names.size + 1; name <- names) yield new ListItem(
  name,
  x = 20
  y = 128 * a
  size = 128
)
```

Now of course this would create a "cross-product" and print:

```
Boris Anna Markus Simone
Boris Anna Markus Simone
Boris Anna Markus Simone
Boris Anna Markus Simone
```

while the wanted result would be

```
Boris
Anna
Markus
Simone
```

But how else can I bind the index to the actual variable? I mean if I'd do a counter like:

```
for(a <- 0 to 1; b <- 0 to 1)
yield(a,b)
```

I'd get

```
Vector((0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1))
```

but if I'd want to I could to `(for a <- 0 to 1; b <- 0 to a) yield(a,b)` and get

```
Vector((0,0), (1,0), (1,1))
```

I have no idea how to do that with my example tho.

Comment: Easy workaround: `zipWithIndex` + `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `zipWithIndex`, which will create a new `Seq` containing each element from the original `Seq`, tupled with it's index within the `Seq`.

```
scala> names.zipWithIndex
res2: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((Boris,0), (Anna,1), (Markus,2), (Simone,3))
```

Which you can then use:

```
val names = Seq[String]("Boris", "Anna", "Markus", "Simone")
class ListItem(name: String, x: Int, y: Int, size: Int)

scala> for ((name, index) <- names.zipWithIndex) 
           yield new ListItem(name, 20, 128 * index, 128)
res0: Seq[ListItem] = List(ListItem@5956b37d, ListItem@4b22015d, ListItem@2587a734, ListItem@6cf25a2b)
```

Which can also be written as a `map`:

```
names.zipWithIndex.map { case (name, index) =>
    new ListItem(name, 20, 128 * index, 128)
}
```

Comment: In your case, you'll have to add one to `index` if you want it one-indexed.